# Python multi threading

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have to write  Python program that spawns 3 threads. Pass a  ID to each thread as a parameter (numbers 1 through 3). In each thread, call the following JSON endpoint substituting {ID} with the ID passed to the thread.

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{ID}

Parse the JSON string into a dict in each thread before returning it to the main thread. Combine the results of all child threads into a list in the main thread.my code like below

```
import threading 
import requests 
import json 
import queue 

q = queue.Queue() 

def main():
   th_list=[]
   for i in range(1,4):
       t = threading.Thread(target=call_url, args=(i,q))
       th_list.append(t)
   print(th_list)
   for thread in th_list:
       thread.start()  
   #for thread in th_list:
       #print(thread.join())
   print(q.get())
    def call_url(i,q):
   url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + str(i)
   response=requests.get(url)
   o_dict=json.loads(response.content)
   q.put(o_dict)

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

But that gets me `None` as the result. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You commented out the joins, so it will complete before the threads finish.

Comment: I tried with join as well but i got only one record expecting 3 records

Comment: But you are only called `get` once after the joins. So of course there is only one seen. The others are waiting there in queue. Iterate the queue or call `get` a few more times. Check the docs to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks Antimony it is working fine now. :)